# NSGridView not available in Storyboard?

Tags: macos, cocoa, gridview, storyboard

I want to use a NSGridView to build a preferences window but it seems that I can't use/layout it in the Storyboard. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NSGridView is available in Interface Builder starting with Xcode 10.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Too bad since NSGridView is a highly visual layout system.

Comment: WWDC is not that far away :)

Comment: I can only suggest to fill a bug report

Comment: Not optimal, but you can do the view in code and use IBDesignable to at least preview it in Interface Builder

Comment: Yes :( Please fill a bug report as well.